# Where should I save static resources for my Django project?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a website for a nonprofit i'm part of using Python/Django.
The format is this: Urls point to Views which point to HTML Templates.
I can't for the life of me figure out where to store the images and stylesheets the HTML needs. Static? Media? Next to the templates? Next to the views? Nothing works.
I'm trying to use img src='image.jpg' and link rel='stylesheet' href='base.css' like I was taught, but it isn't working.

I'd stop development and study up on how files work, but I have a deadline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please make it easy for us to help you by adding some relevant code and by being more descriptive than "but it isn't working".

Comment: And please tag thoroughly. You're missing a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [part 6 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial06/):

> stylesheet (polls/static/polls/style.css):

and

> Next, add the following at the top of
> polls/templates/polls/index.html:
>
> ```
> {% load static %}
>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
> ```
>
> The {% static %} template tag generates the absolute URL of static
> files.
>
> That’s all you need to do for development.

---

> I'm trying to use img href='image.jpg'

It's `<img src="..." alt="...">`